# How to write this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table containing users... one way or another some users were doubled up (have multiple records). I want to pull every user record distinctly by email address and for the users who have multiple records I want to pull only the record that has the most logins.

```
--USERS----------------------------
ID EMAIL           TOTAL_LOGINS
1  blah@blah.com   3
2  blah@blah.com   1
3  bloop@blah.com  1
4  bloop@blah.com  45
5  blarp@blah.com  6
6  flag@blah.com   2
```

What I would like the query to return is this:

```
ID EMAIL           TOTAL_LOGINS
1  blah@blah.com   3
4  bloop@blah.com  45
5  blarp@blah.com  6
6  flag@blah.com   2
```

Can someone help me with this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT    EMAIL, MAX(TOTAL_LOGINS)
FROM      USERS
GROUP BY  EMAIL
```

**EDIT:**

This will do what you want in MS SQL.

```
SELECT    * -- Bad practice. I'm just showing that you can select anything.
FROM      USERS
WHERE     ID = (SELECT    TOP 1 ID
                FROM      USERS u
                WHERE     u.EMAIL = USERS.EMAIL
                ORDER BY  TOTAL_LOGINS DESC)
```

Comment: @Justin: I need the ID of the user as well... in fact I just summarized the table above... there are actually many more columns in the table and I need to do a select * on the users table.

Comment: @marc - But that's what the OP wants. `flag@blah.com` is in the desired results.

Comment: @Martin: his question and the output don't quite match on that point... (at least it's not quite clear for me what he really wants....)

Answer (score 4):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMAIL ORDER BY TOTAL_LOGINS DESC) Corr
   FROM USERS
)

SELECT ID, EMAIL, TOTAL_LOGINS
FROM CTE
WHERE Corr = 1
```

Comment: this is not pulling distinctly by email-address

Comment: @Raffael1984 - You are right, I missed that part of the question. I added that to my answer now.

Comment: @yper - The OP has specified in a comment "there are actually many more columns in the table and I need to do a select * on the users table"

Comment: Yes, you are right. Justin's solution is simple but does cannot show id or other fields for the table. It would need a second `join` or `in` to do that. This solution is far better. That's why I upvoted this one. I just couldn't resist making a comment. You could say I'm jealous as MySQL doesn't have windowing clauses.

Answer (score 1):

in mysql it would look something like that:

```
select * from users where email = '[...]' order by total_logins desc limit 1;
```

I guess your solution would look pretty similar.

Comment: It would be `SELECT TOP 1` instead of `... limit 1` in MS SQL.